# Cómo puedo corregir el error “TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' en mi código?

Tags: python

me encuentro haciendo un reto sobre temperaturas y me sale un error que no comprendo (apenas estoy empezando) e intentado de todo y no he podido solucionarlo
este es mi código

```
Temperaturas_Max = []
Temperaturas_Min = []
Contador_Dias = 0
Dias_Error = 0
Contador_Max = 0
Contador_Min = 0
Contador_Ambos = 0
while True:
    Temperatura_Max = float(input("Ingresa la temperatura Maxima tomada: "))
    Temperatura_Min = float(input("Ingresa la temperatura Minima tomada: "))
    if Temperatura_Max !=0 and Temperatura_Min !=0:
        Contador_Dias = Contador_Dias + 1
    if Temperatura_Max > 35 or Temperatura_Min < 5:
        Dias_Error = Dias_Error + 1
        if Temperaturas_Max == 0 and Temperatura_Min == 0:
            Dias_Error = Dias_Error - 1    
    if Temperatura_Max > 35 and Temperatura_Min < 5:
        Contador_Ambos = Contador_Ambos + 1
        Contador_Max = Contador_Max - 1
        Contador_Min = Contador_Min - 1
    if Temperaturas_Max > 35:
        Contador_Max = Contador_Max + 1
    if Temperatura_Min < 5:
        if Temperatura_Max == 0 and Temperatura_Min ==0:
           Contador_Min = Contador_Min
        else:
            Contador_Min = Contador_Min + 1 
    if Temperatura_Max <= 35 and Temperatura_Min >= 5 and Temperatura_Max!= 0:
        Temperaturas_Max.append(Temperatura_Max)
        Temperaturas_Min.append(Temperatura_Min)
    if Temperatura_Max == 0 and Temperatura_Min == 0:
        break
Suma_Temp_Max = sum(Temperaturas_Max)
Suma_Temp_Min = sum(Temperaturas_Min)
Media_Max = Suma_Temp_Max/(Contador_Dias-Dias_Error)
Media_Min = Suma_Temp_Min/(Contador_Dias-Dias_Error)
Porcentaje_Dias_Error = (Dias_Error/Contador_Dias)*100
print(Contador_Dias)
print(Dias_Error)
print(Contador_Min)
print(Contador_Max)
print(Contador_Ambos)
print(Media_Max)
print(Media_Min)
print(Porcentaje_Dias_Error)
```

a ejecutarlo me dice que el error está en la linea 21

> PS C:\Python> & "C:/Users/Míchel
> Sánchez/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe"
> c:/Python/reto3f.py
> Ingresa la temperatura Maxima tomada: 34
> Ingresa la temperatura Minima tomada: 12
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Python\reto3f.py", line 21, in 
> if Temperaturas_Max > 35:
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
> PS C:\Python>

deja una imagen: [image: error que me aparece en el visual studio code]

gracias de antemano

Comment: El error lo tienes aquí `Temperaturas_Max > 35`, `Temperaturas_Max` es una lista y no es válido compararlo con un entero. Lo que veo que el código que has pegado como texto es diferente al de la imagen y esto ya está corregido, la variable en realidad debería ser `Temperatura_Max`.

Answer (score 2):

Tu error es que dices

```
   if Temperaturas_Max > 35:
        Contador_Max = Contador_Max + 1
```

donde `Temperaturas_Max` es una lista, en lugar de

```
   if Temperatura_Max > 35:
        Contador_Max = Contador_Max + 1
```

con `Temperatura_Max`, el valor ingresado.

Comment: no comprendo todavía, ¿como podría solucionarlo? tendría que quitar la lista y pasarlo a una variable normal?

Comment: @Yused. Te equivocastes al escribir el nombre de la variable. Borra la 's' en `Temperaturas_Max > 35:`. Tu intención es contar las veces que la temperatura excede los 35 grados.

Comment: @Yused estas usando la variable equivoca, es eso, ya que `Temperaturas_Max` es una lista

Comment: aaa, comprendo estaba tomando la variable que no era, Muchas gracias me salvaron.